# Dual Monitor issue in Ubuntu 14.04 ATI

Tags: ati, multiple-monitors, display-resolution

I have a ATI Radeon 7730M Driver, and have the Catalyst Control Center installed. I have an external monitor with recommended resolution of 1920x1080 and the laptop's inbuilt monitor 1366x768. Whenever I connect the external monitor to my laptop as an extended monitor, the screen starts flickering. 
It doesn't do so when I mirror the displays, or change the GPU to the inbuilt Intel GPU.

I tried using the command when on the ATI GPU

```
xrandr --output LDHMI1 --auto --left-of LVDS1 --output VGA1 --auto --scale 1.0001x1.0001
```

The flickering stops then, but the screen doesn't load correctly, with the 22'' external monitor having only 15'6 of the screen working, and on dragging anything beyond that it loads in the laptop's inbuilt monitor.

Please do suggest what to do so I can use my AMD GPU and the external monitor without any further issues. I am using Ubuntu 14.04

This is the output of `xrandr -q`:

```
Screen 0: minimum 320 x 200, current 1920 x 1080, maximum 8192 x 8192
LVDS1 connected 1366x768+1920+0 (normal left inverted right x axis y axis) 344mm x 193mm
   1366x768       60.1*+   40.1  
   1360x768       59.8     60.0  
   1024x768       60.0  
   800x600        60.3     56.2  
   640x480        59.9  
VGA1 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
HDMI1 connected primary 1920x1080+0+0 (normal left inverted right x axis y axis) 477mm x 268mm
   1920x1080      60.0*+   50.0     59.9  
   1920x1080i     60.1     50.0     60.0  
   1680x1050      59.9  
   1600x900       60.0  
   1280x1024      75.0     60.0  
   1280x800       59.9  
   1152x864       75.0  
   1280x720       60.0     50.0     59.9  
   1440x576i      50.1  
   1024x768       75.1     60.0  
   1440x480i      60.1     60.1  
   832x624        74.6  
   800x600        75.0     60.3  
   720x576        50.0  
   720x480        60.0     59.9  
   640x480        75.0     60.0     59.9  
   720x400        70.1  
DP1 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
```